# Relative path in settings.py in django

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, relative-path

for various settings(MEDIA_ROOT,TEMPLATE_DIRS) in setting.py it is instructed to give absolute path.I have configured apache with mod_wsgi.I have a wsgi script in the folder named `apache` that redirects to `settings.py`.

```
import os
import sys

path = 'D:/Projects/Dan'

if path not in sys.path:
  sys.path.append(path )

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'Django.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

(don't misunderstand - Django is the name of my project.)

Okay my question is - now that we have imported the path to my project to system path in the wsgi script, isn't it more feasible that I give a relative path in `settings.py`,since that would make deploying easier.If I am wrong please tell me the standard procedure so that I can set all the path in one file other than 3 files(Apache - httpd.conf, mod_wsgi - django.wsgi, django - settings.py).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
import os
this_directory = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

and then:

```
absolute_directory = os.path.join(this_directory, 'relative.txt')
```

BTW, calling your project 'Django' is ill advised given that Django package itself is 'django'. You shouldn't rely on differences in case not causing confusion. In short, Python packages/module names should ever differ just by case. Your site project directory is treated as a Python package and thus the problem.

Comment: I have my orders.No choice.. My question was since my project directory is already on the system path why can I not use relative path ?

Comment: Because sys.path is module search path and completely different to file system current working directory for process. The current working directory can be anything under Apache and will not be the directory where manage.py is like when using Django development server. See the documentation http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Application_Working_Directory